# MAC OSX MySQL Query Log not writing

Tags: mysql

I have my my.cnf with this setting

```
[mysqld]
general_log =1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysqld.log
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=64M
```

also had it before set to

```
[mysqld]
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
query_cache_type=1
query_cache_size=64M
```

I know I had this working at  one point but when I went to go tail it today I noticed it wasn't working. I have the file in /var/log and this is the permissions

-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  wheel        0 Jul 26 10:27 mysqld.log

It was

-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel        0 Jul 26 10:27 mysqld.log

Answer (score 0):

The problem might the your version of mysql - general_log_file only works on versions 5.1.29 and above. If you have a lesser version (5.1.28 or lower, any 5.0), you have to use "log" not "general_log_file."

If this isn't it, let us know here and we'll take another run at it.